# Complex calculation of the hours amount

Tags: sqlite, epoch

I have a Pythonic system that stores student absences data in a SQLite database. Each row includes the start and end time of the absence, represented by the number of seconds since Jan 01 1970. I was asked to add a feature which limits the number of hours of absence per week.

It sounds easy to pull out the amount of hours, using a statement like this:

```sql
SELECT (sum(ending-starting)/3600) 
FROM requests
WHERE student_id = {x}
AND starting BETWEEN {y} AND ({y}+604800)
AND approved = 1
```

The problem is that the limit must only be the hours defined as "mandatory presence." For example, if a user has defined the hours 8:00 to 17:00 as a "mandatory presence," an absence that begins on Sunday at 14:00 and ends on Monday at the same time, will be calculated in the code above 24 hours, while in practice it is only 9 hours.

"Mandatory presence" is defined in the database as two numerical parameters: "morning" and "evening" (always a round hour). Is there a way to make the calculation above taking into account these two numbers?
If it can not be done in sql, I would love to hear how to select the data in sql and then perform the calculation in python.

Comment: Do you need to solve this in the database SQL or can you pull all the database absence and mandatory times and solve the problem in python. Your question is tagged with python but no python related stuff in your question.

Comment: As I wrote at the end, I don't care if the problem will be resolved in sql or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MikeT's answer is not entirely working, but it certainly helped me reach the desired result. Here's the perfect statement:

```
SELECT
(
    sum((
        (ending - starting)
        -(
            CASE WHEN starting < strftime('%s',date(starting,'unixepoch')||printf(' %02d:00', morning))
            THEN strftime('%s',date(starting,'unixepoch')||printf(' %02d:00', morning)) - starting 
            ELSE 0 
            END
            +
            CASE WHEN ending > strftime('%s',date(ending,'unixepoch')||printf(' %02d:00', evening))
            THEN ending - strftime('%s',date(ending,'unixepoch')||printf(' %02d:00', evening))
            ELSE 0 
            END
        )
    ) /3600.0
    -(
      (24-evening+morning)
      *
      (round(julianday(ending, 'unixepoch'))-round(julianday(starting, 'unixepoch')))
    )
)) AS ha
FROM requests
INNER JOIN students ON requests.student_id = students.ID
INNER JOIN institutes ON students.inst_id = institutes.ID
WHERE student_id = {x}
AND starting BETWEEN {y} AND ({y}+604800)
AND approved = 1;
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following may do what you wish :-

```
SELECT
    (
        sum((
            (ending - starting)
            -(
                CASE WHEN starting < strftime('%s',date(starting,'unixepoch')||' 08:00') 
                THEN strftime('%s',date(starting,'unixepoch')||' 08:00') - starting 
                ELSE 0 
                END
                +
                CASE WHEN ending > strftime('%s',date(starting,'unixepoch')||' 17:00') 
                THEN ending - strftime('%s',date(starting,'unixepoch')||' 17:00') 
                ELSE 0 
                END
            )
        ) /3600)
) AS ha, *
FROM requests
WHERE student_id = {x}
AND starting BETWEEN {y} AND ({y}+604800)
AND approved = 1
;
```